# How to split and remove a string in a list?

Tags: python

Here's my example code:

```
list1 = [{'name': 'foobar', 'parents': 'John Doe and Bartholomew Shoe'},
     {'name': 'Wisteria Ravenclaw', 'parents': 'Douglas Lyphe and Jackson Pot'
    }]
```

I need to split parent into a list and remove 'and' string. So the output should look like this:

```
list1 = [{'name': 'foobar', 'parents': ['John Doe', 'Bartholomew Shoe'],
     {'name': 'Wisteria Ravenclaw', 'parents': ['Douglal Lyphe', 'Jackson', 'Pot']
    }]
```

Please help me figure this out.

```
for people in list1:
    people['parents'] = people['parents'].split('and')
```

I'm not sure how to move that ', ' string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `people` inside loop, not the iterator itself.

```
for people in list1:
    people['parents'] = people['parents'].split(' and ')
```

and then when you print `list1`, you get:

```
[{'name': 'foobar', 'parents': ['John Doe', 'Bartholomew Shoe']}, {'name': 'Wisteria Ravenclaw', 'parents': ['Douglas Lyphe', 'Jackson Pot']}]
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped that. That's what I did and I got.

     list1 = [{'name': 'foobar', 'parents': ['John Doe , Bartholomew Shoe'],

but I need it to be like


list1 = [{'name': 'foobar', 'parents': ['John Doe', 'Bartholomew Shoe'],

Comment: @Nick, please look the output again. It's same as you need.

Comment: I notice the ' and ' now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what others said: You may want to split on a regular expression so that

- you don't split on `and` in case a name happens to contain that substring,
- you remove the whitespace around `and`.

Like so:

```
import re

list1 = [
  {'name': 'foobar', 'parents': 'John Doe and Bartholomew Shoe'},
  {'name': 'Wisteria Ravenclaw', 'parents': 'Douglas Lyphe and Jackson Pot'}
]

for people in list1:
    people['parents'] = re.split(r'\s+and\s+', people['parents'])

print(list1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I've haven't reached regex yet, but I'll take a look at what you suggested and learn em up. :)